# Could not resolve 'CustomTransform' as a type of Transform

Tags: .net, msbuild, web.config-transform

I've made a custom web.config transform, we'll call it CustomTransform, following the example on appharbor [here](https://blog.appharbor.com/2012/07/27/custom-web-config-transforms-and-merges). Like the one in the example, mine inherits from Transform. I have also made sure to import my custom transform like this:

**<xdt:Import path=".\bin\CustomTransformAssembly.dll" namespace="CustomTransformAssembly.Build.Transforms"/>**

I can run the build at this point with no issues. It's only when I try using the CustomTransform that I have any problems. The transform is being used like this

**<add name="AConfigElement" connectionString="a-connection-string" xdt:Transform="CustomTransform" />**

But, when I run msbuild on this project, I get the following error:

**error : Could not resolve 'CustomTransform' as a type of Transform**

How am I supposed to be referencing the CustomTransform so that msbuild will find it?

Comment: Would adding references to the missing types help? See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ce4cb7ef-8e8d-4773-8b20-56f1c209d6f5/could-not-resolve-type-httpschemasmicrosoftcomwinfx2006xamlpresentationpointcollection?forum=wfprerelease

Answer (score 0):

I am using a CustomTransformation and have exactly the same issue, and in my case I have to overriding ToolsVersion for MsBuild, `/tv:4.0` works for me.

The project I has was converted from VS 2008 to VS 2010 and then to VS 2013 project, and somehow after manually edit the `.csproj` and change the project property to  `ToolsVersion=12.0`, CustomTransformation start to fail, after a bit of trail and error, I found it is has something to do with MsBuild ToolsVersion.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after starting to use Visual Studio 2019.
To resolve the error I had to:

- Remove some old transformation related xml from the .csproj file
- Make sure, the referenced library with the custom transformation referenced the same version of Microsoft.Web.Xdt (2.1.1) - the same as SlowCheetah is using at the moment. Tried it with binding redirects first but it didn't help.

[image: changes to csproj]

Deleted lines as text:

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="SlowCheetah">
    <SlowCheetahToolsPath>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath( $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\packages\SlowCheetah.2.5.14\tools\))</SlowCheetahToolsPath>
    <SlowCheetah_EnableImportFromNuGet Condition=" '$(SlowCheetah_EnableImportFromNuGet)'=='' ">true</SlowCheetah_EnableImportFromNuGet>
    <SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath Condition=" '$(SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath)'=='' ">$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath( $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Properties\SlowCheetah\SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets ))</SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath>
    <SlowCheetahTargets Condition=" '$(SlowCheetah_EnableImportFromNuGet)'=='true' and Exists('$(SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath)') ">$(SlowCheetah_NuGetImportPath)</SlowCheetahTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
  <Target Name="AfterCompile" Condition="Exists('app.$(Configuration).config')">
    <!--Generate transformed app config in the intermediate directory-->
    <TransformXml Source="app.config" Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config" Transform="app.$(Configuration).config" />
    <!--Force build process to use the transformed configuration file from now on.-->
    <ItemGroup>
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="app.config" />
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config">
        <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
      </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <!--Override After Publish to support ClickOnce AfterPublish. Target replaces the untransformed config file copied to the deployment directory with the transformed one.-->
  <Target Name="AfterPublish">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <DeployedConfig>$(_DeploymentApplicationDir)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt).config$(_DeploymentFileMappingExtension)</DeployedConfig>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <!--Publish copies the untransformed App.config to deployment directory so overwrite it-->
    <Copy Condition="Exists('$(DeployedConfig)')" SourceFiles="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config" DestinationFiles="$(DeployedConfig)" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="$(SlowCheetahTargets)" Condition="Exists('$(SlowCheetahTargets)')" Label="SlowCheetah" />
```

Added by Visual Studio while previewing the transformation):

```
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.3.2.26\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.3.2.26\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets'))" />
  </Target>


<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.3.2.26\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.3.2.26\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets')" />
```